# Give a proof of validity and indicate the law used

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Below is what I'm trying to solve, I got to a certain point but am stuck. Can someone assist me with the correct steps to solve this?  I could have potentially did a lot of it wrong too =/

Problem:

---

All cephalopods live in the ocean. No humans live in the ocean. Plato and Socrates are
humans. Therefore, Plato is not a cephalopod.

c(x) is a cephalopod,
O(x) lives in the ocean,
H(x) is a human,
and the domain of each propositional function consists of all organisms.

---

Symbolic Notation

∀x [C(x) -> O(x)]

∀x [H(x) -> ¬O(x)]

H(Plato) ^ H (Socrates)

therefore ¬(C(Plato))

```
Statement:                       Reason:

1. ∀x [H(x) -> ¬O(x)]              Premise

2. H(Plato) ^ H (Socrates)          Premise

3. H(Plato)                         Simplification (from 2)

4. H(Plato) -> ¬O(Plato)            Universal Instantiation (from 1)

5. ¬O(Plato)                        Modus Ponens (from 3, 4)

6. ∀x [C(x) -> O(x)]               Premise
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks okay so far.  Just continue with more like it.

Namely, use Universal Instantiation, then Modus Tollens.

Comment: does the logic look correct? so 7 would be Universal Instantiation, followed by 8 as Modus Tollens with (5,7) which then gets me ¬(C(Plato))?

Comment: @rawr Yes.  Continue in the same manner

Comment: @ Graham Kemp - Thank you so much! Glad to hear my logic was correct for the first half at least.